# Let $f(\theta) = c_0 + c_1 e^{i \theta} + ... + c_n e ^{n i \theta}$. Prove that there exists some $\theta_0$ such that $|f(\theta)| > |c_0|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $c_0,c_1,...,c_n$ be complex numbers and assume that $c_k \ne 0$ for some integer $1 \le k \le n$. Define a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ by

$$f(\theta) = c_0 + c_1 e^{i \theta} + ... + c_n e ^{n i \theta}$$

Prove that there exists some $\theta_0$ with $0 \le \theta_0 \lt 2 \pi$ such that $|f(\theta)| > |c_0|$.

Could someone help me prove this? I have literally gotten no where, I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(z) = c_0+c_1z+...+c_n z^n$ and note that $g$ is non constant and $g(0) = c_0$.

Note that $f(\theta) =g(e^{i \theta})$ and apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: Okay I will try that now.

Answer (score 1):

The average of the square of the modulus of $f$ on the interval ($L^2$-norm) is the sum of square of the modulus of the $c_i$ (Plancherel formula). So the average of the square of the modulus of $f$ is strictly greater than $\vert c_0 \vert^2$.By continuity, it must be strictly greater somewhere.

Comment: Bessel's inequality might be more appropriate?

Comment: For finite sums, there is no much difference. Btw this is the standard proof of the maximum modulus principle...